# PHP script misbehaving

Tags: php

I have a small script that defines a variable called `$prPrice`. This script is not working in the way that I intend, as in some of the products that contain a certain department code are display prices relating to other department codes. So i assume that the way i have initially put this together is somehow wrong.

My question would be this, can anyone spot a problem with, or provide suggestions for bettering the following simple php script:

```
// Cost plus 2.5%
if ($prDept = (204 || 205 || 209 || 1501 || 1601 )) {
    if ($_SESSION['tax'] == "on" || !isset($_SESSION['tax']))
        $prPrice = ((($prCost1 / 1.14) * 1.025) * 1.14);
    else if ($_SESSION['tax'] == "off" && $prTaxable == "1")
        $prPrice = ($prCost1 * 1.025);
    else if ($_SESSION['tax'] == "off" && $prTaxable == "0")
        $prPrice = (($prCost1 / 1.14) * 1.025);
```

}

Comment: you are not optimizing anything, your script doesn't work right. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization

Comment: "Optimizing" is _not_ a synonym for "fixing". And how are we supposed to deduce what you intended from code that, by your own admission, doesn't do that thing?

Comment: @Tomalak good point and thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$prDept = (204 || 205 || 209 || 1501 || 1601)
```

That is not how this works in PHP. It really needs to look like...

```
$prDept == 204 || $prDept == 205 || $prDept == 209 || $prDept == 1501 || $prDept == 1601
```

or alternatively,

```
in_array($prDept, array(204, 205, 209, 1501, 1601))
```

Comment: This mistake comes from the common English error "my A can be X or Y or Z", which in fact should read "my A can be X, or my A can be Y, or my A can be Z". Direct correlation. Try not to think of programming languages as English, because they are not as forgiving when you remove logical consistency from your expressions.

Comment: (If you *really* want to think of an English version, the proper one for relating to programming languages would be "my A can be one of the values X, Y, or Z", where X,Y,Z is a set (or an array, in this case).)

Comment: @Amber I see where you are going with this, i think what i was trying to accomplish would be something more like the latter. I appreciate your input, and thank again!

Comment: @Amber: I was trying to make a more general grammatical correlation, but, sure.

Comment: @Tomalak Say for instance, there were two sets of this script, each relating to different departments. Would it be better to arrange this as an if, else if. Or have it as two seperate if's?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($prDept == 204 || $prDept == 205 || $prDept == 209 || $prDept == 1501 || $prDept == 1601) {
    if ($_SESSION['tax'] == "on" || !isset($_SESSION['tax'])) {
          $prPrice = ((($prCost1 / 1.14) * 1.025) * 1.14);
    } else if ($_SESSION['tax'] == "off" && $prTaxable == "1") {
          $prPrice = ($prCost1 * 1.025);
    } else if ($_SESSION['tax'] == "off" && $prTaxable == "0") {
          $prPrice = (($prCost1 / 1.14) * 1.025);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
$departments = array(204 , 205 , 209 ,1501, 1601);

if (in_array($prDept, $departments)) {
 ...
}
```